# Install glade for windows through unpack

Tags: haskell, glade, gtk2hs

I'm trying to install glade for my GTK Haskell binding. The cabal install fails to resolve dependencies and trying to install the unpacked version gives me this error:

```
SetupWrapper.hs:118:28: Warning:
    In the use of `configCompiler'
    (imported from Distribution.Simple.Configure):
    Deprecated: "'configCompiler' is deprecated. Use 'configCompilerEx' instead."
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Gtk2HsSetup.o )

Gtk2HsSetup.hs:161:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO
                                    (Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo.InstalledPackageInfo_
                                       ModuleName)'
                with actual type `FilePath
                                  -> PackageDB
                                  -> IO Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo.InstalledPackageInfo'
    Probable cause: `generateRegistrationInfo' is applied to too few arguments
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      installedPkgInfoRaw <- generateRegistrationInfo
                               verbosity pkg lib lbi clbi inplace distPref
    In the expression:
      do { installedPkgInfoRaw <- generateRegistrationInfo
                                    verbosity pkg lib lbi clbi inplace distPref;
           dllsInScope <- getSearchPath >>= (filterM doesDirectoryExist)
                          >>= getDlls;
           let libs = fixLibs dllsInScope (extraLibraries installedPkgInfoRaw)
               installedPkgInfo = ...;
           case () of {
             _ | modeGenerateRegFile -> die "Generate Reg File not supported"
               | modeGenerateRegScript -> die "Generate Reg Script not supported"
               | otherwise
               -> registerPackage
                    verbosity installedPkgInfo pkg lbi inplace packageDbs } }

Gtk2HsSetup.hs:162:63:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Bool'
    Expected type: Bool
      Actual type: FilePath
    In the 7th argument of `generateRegistrationInfo', namely
      `distPref'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      installedPkgInfoRaw <- generateRegistrationInfo
                               verbosity pkg lib lbi clbi inplace distPref
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compile against the wrong version of something. You say Cabal "could not resolve dependencies"; can you be a bit more specific? What is it complaining about?

Comment: When I try and install Glade it tries to use older versions of Cairo and GTK. When I try and install those versions of the packages it refuses.